# Finding an integral $\int g(x)^j dx $ from $\int g(x)^2 dx $

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

let  $I = \int_0^1 g(x)^2 dx $, where $g$ is a real valued function.
With this information is it possible to give an upper bound
for $\int_0^1 g(x)^j dx $? Here $j$ is a natural number.
When $j=1$ I can apply Cauchy-Schwarz, but I am curious about when $j>2$.
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no general upper bound. For instance, let $g(x) = x^{-1/3}$. Then $\displaystyle \int_0^1 g(x)^2 \, dx = 3$, but $\displaystyle \int_0^1 g(x)^3 \, dx = \infty$.

Answer (score 1):

No, the higher $j$ values can be as large as you want.  Consider $g$ that is $j$ on $[0,1/j^2]$ and $0$ otherwise.

Comment: This was helpful too. Thank you for the answer!